# How to read the bit of switch of PLC in C# application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, plc, plc4x

i am working on read and write the Mitsubishi PLC via C# application i need to read the date and time of plc and display in the datagridview in application. If i store a date example Year,Month and Day in D111,D112,D113 then i read the date sucessfully but the problem is year is stored in D111,Month and Day are store in switch D112 bytes 0-7 and bytes 8-15. if i read D111 and D112 then the date will be displayed like 2022/0309 but i need 2022/03/09 . how can i read the bytes 0-7 and 8-15 separately .

```
int count;
       plc.GetDevice("D22", out count);
       int result;
       plc.GetDevice("D22", out result);
       int read_;
       plc.GetDevice("D22", out read_);
       int read1;
       plc.GetDevice("D22", out read1);
       int year;
       plc.GetDevice("D220", out year);
       int month;
       plc.GetDevice("D221", out month);
       int day;
       plc.GetDevice("D222", out day);
       int hour;
       plc.GetDevice("D223", out hour);
       int minute;
       plc.GetDevice("D224", out minute);
       int second;
       plc.GetDevice("D225", out second);
       SqlCommand cmd;

       cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Table](date,time,count,tool,up,down) values(@date,@time,@count,@tool,@up,@down)", con);
       con.Open();



       {

           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString() + "/" + day.ToString());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", hour.ToString() + ":" + minute.ToString() + ":" + second.ToString());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count.ToString());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tool", read1.ToString());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@up", result.ToString());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@down", read_.ToString());
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
           DisplayData();
           ClearData();
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you really need to directly read a BYTE from the PLC, but this can be easily achieved by manually splitting the data into bytes:

```
int monthAndDay; 
plc.GetDevice("D112", out monthAndDay);

//monthAndDay will get something like x0903 (hex)
//Then we split it into bytes 
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(monthAndDay);

//And then we get the data. Just check if the first byte really is the Month in the PLC
int month = bytes[0];
int day = bytes[1];
```

**Recommendation:**
Change the description of your question from "Bits" to "Bytes", because that's what your question is about. ;)